# SBT. Clean local repository

Tags: scala, sbt

How I can delete my project from local repository? I previously published it using `publish-local` SBT command.

I want to clean all compiled and cached stuff because I don't see any changes in my project after recompiling it and redeploying on server.

Comment: A quick `rm -rf *`  based on your ivy repository's root directory isn't enough?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retry `sbt publishLocal`, add your module version `x.x.x-SNAPSHOT`.

Answer (score 1):

Run `publishLocal` again and note where it writes the published `jar`s to. For me, it was `~/.ivy2/local`. Removing this directory cleared the locally published repository.

Answer (score -1):

There is a sbt command `clean`. if you need you can add additional folders to clean task in your build file

```
cleanFiles <+= baseDirectory { base => base / "temp" }
```

Comment: `sbt clean` remove files in `./target` folder in current project. Question is how to delete artifact from `~/.ivy2/local` folder.